# List <> and loops in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I want to warn that it may seem like a silly question, and in general shitcode, but I'm just learning and I'm deadlocked.

```
private static ProductApi ProductApi = null;
private static AttachApi attachApi = null;
private static String productname;
private static String productId;
private static String attach;

....//output usage information for this simple

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ... // check and save parameters

        List<Product> Products = null;
        try {
            ProductPageFilter pageFilter = PageFilterFactory.getAllRows(ProductColumn.Product_ID);
            Products = ProductApi.getProducts(pageFilter);
        } catch (SdkFault e) {
            System.err.println("getProducts() failed: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        if (Products == null || Products.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No Products assigned to user '" + username + "'");
        } else {
            for (Product Product : Products) {
                Productname = Product.getName();
                ProductId = Product.getProductId();
            }
        }
        List<AttachComponent> AttachComponents = null;
        try {
            AttachComponents = AttachApi.getAttachComponents(ProductId);
        } catch (SdkFault e) {
            System.err.println("AttachApi.getAttachComponents() failed");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        for (AttachComponent AttachComponent : AttachComponents) {
            Attach = AttachComponent.getComponentName();
            System.out.println("ProductName: " + Productname + " ID: " + ProductId + " Attach: " + Attach);
        }
    } catch ...
```

It turns out:

```
/ProjectName: Iphone 3gs ID: 2345hjh Attach: red case
/ProjectName: Iphone 3gs ID: 2345hjh Attach: red case
/ProjectName: Iphone 3gs ID: 2345hjh Attach: red case
/ProjectName: Iphone 3gs ID: 2345hjh Attach: red case
```

I want so:

```
/ProjectName: Iphone 3gs ID: 2345hj Attach: red case
/ProjectName: Iphone 3gs ID: 2345hj Attach: blue stick
/ProjectName: Iphone 3gs ID: 2345hj Attach: white case
/ProjectName: Iphone 5S  ID: 2dhkjd Attach: green window
/ProjectName: Iphone 5S  ID: 2dhkjd Attach: fail setup
/ProjectName: Iphone 5S  ID: 2dhkjd Attach: deep scratch
```

What to do with the cycles?

Comment: Without having the information where and how the Arraylist generation does take place there is not really much that could be done.

Comment: We're missing some essential code here.

Comment: Did you debug to check if the `List`s actually contain what you expect them to contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you want:

```
    List<Product> products = null;
    try {
        ProductPageFilter pageFilter = PageFilterFactory.getAllRows(ProductColumn.Product_ID);
        products = ProductApi.getProducts(pageFilter);
    } catch (SdkFault e) {
        System.err.println("getProducts() failed: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    if (products == null || products.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No Products assigned to user '" + username + "'");
    } else {
        for (Product product : products) {
            productName = product.getName();
            productId = product.getproductId();
            List<AttachComponent> attachComponents = null;
            try {
                attachComponents = AttachApi.getAttachComponents(productId);
            } catch (SdkFault e) {
                System.err.println("AttachApi.getAttachComponents() failed");
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            for (AttachComponent attachComponent : attachComponents) {
                attach = attachComponent.getComponentName();
                System.out.println("ProductName: " + productName + " ID: " + productId + " Attach: " + attach);
            }
        }
    }
```

i.e. put the second loop **inside** the first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using two for loop one loop's output is the input of another.
You should use second for loop into first for loop
i.e

> for() {
>       for()
>       {
>       }
>    }

i think you should try this.